# ReplayKit not calling stopRecording completion handler sometimes

Tags: ios, replaykit

I'm using iPad WiFi 2017 iOS 11.0.3. It only happens sometimes, and only first time the app is opened. Steps to reproduce it:

1. Open the app
2. Start a new recording
3. Stop it
4. If handler is called, then it worked. Then, to try to reproduce
   the issue again, just close the app by swiping it away, and back to
   step 1.

Is there any way to fix it?